# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) - Emulator Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm running the Android Studio emulator, but the emulator always returns an error. When I look at the device's Logcat, I get the following message. How can I resolve this?

```
2023-07-19 09:33:40,511 [3588630]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel C API 24 - C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_C_API_24
2023-07-19 09:33:40,607 [3588726]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel C API 24 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-07-19 09:33:40,608 [3588727]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel C API 24 - Found systemPath C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\\system-images\android-24\default\armeabi-v7a\
2023-07-19 09:33:41,015 [3589134]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel C API 24 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Gustavo\.android\avd\Pixel_C_API_24.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-07-19 09:33:41,017 [3589136]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel C API 24 - encryption is off
2023-07-19 09:33:44,784 [3592903]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel C API 24 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2023-07-19 09:33:45,698 [3593817]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appCodeVisionSettings took 11 ms, FileTypeManager took 11 ms
2023-07-19 09:33:45,760 [3593879]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_C_API_24 is online, assuming it's not
2023-07-19 09:33:53,839 [3601958]   INFO - #c.i.o.c.i.s.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 8327 ms
2023-07-19 09:33:54,750 [3602869]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appAndroidEditors took 13 ms'
```

I deleted as much as I could from the SSD to free up more memory. I updated the local Java. Currently, it looks like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Gustavo> java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```